# Replacing file in SharePoint folder- new file is displayed in browser, old file displayed in app

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, versioning, version-history, version

Having been working on a document offline for a while, I tried copying it to the relevant folder on SharePoint- which already had the original version of the document.

When dragging my local copy of the file to the folder on SharePoint (online, at: https://mycompany.sharepoint.com), a message was displayed stating:

> A file with this name already exists. Would you like to replace the existing one?

I clicked 'Replace', and saw that the file I had just replaced had "A few seconds ago" written next to it in the 'Modified' column on SharePoint.

However, when I then opened this file 'in app' from SharePoint (ensuring that it was closed on my computer first), the most recent changes I had made to the file were not visible. But, when I opened it 'in browser' from SharePoint, the most recent changes were visible. The local version of Word I have installed on my computer is Office 365 Pro Plus, and the version that is being opened in my browser is also Office 365.

I have tried copying the latest version of the file from my computer to SharePoint in various ways (drag & drop, Upload --> File, Delete the file from SharePoint and copy/ upload it again) but I am still having the same issue.

What is causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Is it some sort of caching error?

**Edit**

So it's a weird one... I have just checked with a colleague- asked them to open the file from SharePoint. When they open it in app from SharePoint, they see the most recent & up-to-date version (the version I have locally on my computer, which I've been trying to copy to SharePoint). However, whenever I open the file in app from SharePoint, I'm seeing an older version. It seems that my local copy has been uploaded to SharePoint, but that there must be some sort of caching error or something, causing me to see the old version when I open it from SharePoint on my computer...

I have tried clearing all my browsing history/ data (including login data), restarted my computer, hard shut down & rebooting my computer, but I'm still having the problem when I open up.

I've also tried looking at the version history in SharePoint- I can see the latest version being when I most recently uploaded the document to the repository, but when I open that in app, it opens as Read Only, and I cant make any changes to it...

Comment: @Tally I've just seen your edit- when I 'open in app', it is opening the document from the local installed instance of Word on my computer- so I'm not sure that this is the web-app you're referring to? Presumably the web-app is what it's opened in when I choose to open the document 'in browser'?

Comment: Yes the web-app is used for the 'open document in browser' option; I thought this might be what you meant by "...when I opened it 'in browser...'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I enventually resolved this (still not sure what was causing it), was the basic approach of uploading the current version of the document to the same SharePoint folder as the original version, but with a different filename.

Then deleting the original version & renaming the current version to the original name. After doing this, I was able to see the most recent version displayed both in browser & in app.

Answer (score 0):

Surfer,

I'm not sure I fully understand the issue you are facing, it does sound like something odd is happening.  Are you using web parts somewhere on the page where you are opening the document from?  Try going to the actual source document, where it is saved to - then try to open from there.

Also check the **Document Library Settings > Advanced Settings**.

- To troubleshoot the issue, you could try changing the settings here and testing the behaviour of opening the file.  (It was for this reason that I tagged your question with 'Office-Web-Apps; though if it transpires that this is not the issue, then perhaps the tag should be removed.)

[image: Opening Documents in the Browser]

A final thought - have you already tried opening the document using a different browser (try using Chrome instead of IE, if you normally use IE).  Perhaps check that another user has the same issue too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tally. The issue I'm having is not with opening the document 'in browser'. When viewing the folder where the document I've just uploaded is located (having replaced the original version of that document), if I click the 'Options' button next to the filename (displayed when the cursor hovers over the filename), and go to the 'Open' menu item, I get the options to open the file 'in browser', or 'in app'.

Comment: If I open in browser, it opens the document in a new tab in my browser, using an Office 365 instance of Word- this shows the latest changes to the document (which were made locally, and copied to SharePoint when I copied the file over a moment ago). However, if I open in app, it opens the document using the locally installed version of Word on my computer (as if I had gone to a Word doc on my C drive and double clicked it). When I open it in app- the most recent changes I had made to the document are not displayed.

Comment: I was using Firefox, however, I've just tried it in both Chrome & IE- and I have exactly the same issue- works fine when viewing the file in the browser, but not when viewing the file in app.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm using SP 2013 and Office 2016, so have no experience of this kind of issue; it sounds like you're using O365 and perhaps Sharepoint Online(?)  I don't think I could do any testing to try to recreate this kind of behaviour since we are working with different platforms.  Perhaps retag your question, remove my tag, it might be worth adding the SP platform too (i.e. 2016, SP-Online or whatever you're using).

Comment: Yep- I'm using SharePoint online (i.e. browsing to https://mycompany.sharepoint.com). Locally, I am using Office 365 Pro Plus.

Answer (score 0):

Is version control enabled on library? Do you have ability in SharePoint interface to check-out, publish this document?

If yes, you probably need to check-out file in SharePoint, then update it the way you want, then check-in and publish. This way you should get the same version in all applications.

Comment: Yes, I do have the ability to checkout & publish in SharePoint- I just tried checking it out, then dragging and dropping my local copy to the folder on SharePoint. When I dropped the new copy to SharePoint, I got the notification saying 'A file with this name already exists... Would you like to replace it?' I said Yes, and the file started coyping. However, I then got a notification saying `The file https://...Design.docx is locked for shared use by user@company.com [membership].` The user it said it was locked by is me- and that is the user I am signed in as on SharePoint... Any ideas?

Comment: I don't usually have to checkout before replacing a file though- it would usually just let me overwrite what is already on SharePoint with my local copy if I happen to have been working offline.

Comment: Notification sounds like you copy file from another user... you could try opening browser as admin... though you copy file by your user. Probably sharepoint lost "link", that file on local drive and online is the same. You could try updating other file and see if it happens again.

Comment: So it's a weird one... I have just checked with a colleague- asked them to open the file from SharePoint. When they open it in app from SharePoint, they see the most recent & up-to-date version (the version I have locally on my computer, which I've been trying to copy to SharePoint). However, whenever I open the file in app from SharePoint, I'm seeing an older version. It seems that my local copy has been uploaded to SharePoint, but that there must be some sort of caching error or something, causing me to see the old version when I open it from SharePoint on my computer...