# Links to documents not opening in application

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, navigation, hyperlink

I have links to a few documents on my home navigation across the top and left side of my page.  When I click on the document link on my navigation it asks me to save or open the document.  It use to behave as if I clicked on the document link it would open in the application.  If I go to the library where the documents are located the document opens in the application.  It should work both ways if I click on the document link from the side or top navigation.  There is also no error that appears just doesn't open in the application.  BTW I did not change any settings...etc. it just stopped working.

Has anyone else experienced this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, when i click on the document link on the navigation, or when i open the document link directly, it asks me to save or open the document.

This link will open the link in client application, change the link in the following format and compare the results:

[ms-word:ofe|u|https://someurl.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/Shared%20Documents/WordDoc1.docx](http://ms-word:ofe%7Cu%7Chttps://someurl.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/Shared%20Documents/WordDoc1.docx)

When we go to the library where the documents are located, the document opens in the client application, it is because "SharePoint OpenDocuments Class" managed addon works fine.

Comment: Thanks.  Following your format is there a way that it can be added across the entire library without going per document?  I guess I would have to remember when adding documents to the navigation to change the format. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't make any changes, try it on other browser. Then check the Document Library Settings > Advanced Settings:

[image: Library Advanced Settings]

[Manual from this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/276363/replacing-file-in-sharepoint-folder-new-file-is-displayed-in-browser-old-file)

Your links in nav are not changed until you do that, but doc library has common settings for it's documents.